# Exportar banco de dados MySQL para SQLite

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Normalmente utilizo um banco de dados nas aplicações que desenvolvo localmente.

Com o `mysql` sempre que preciso trabalhar clonar a aplicação para outra maquina, preciso gerar um `dump` do banco e importar na base local novamente. Penso que poderia eliminar algum esforço desnecessário usando uma base `SQLite` que seria armazenada no repositório junto com os arquivos da aplicação.

**Q:** Como faço converter/exportar uma base **MySQL** para um arquivo do **SQLite**?

Se puder ser feito `prompt` do `mysql` ou do `linux` melhor.

Creio que versionar o banco dessa forma pode não ser recomendado em casos onde mais de uma pessoa esteja manipulando os dados da base. Mas isso não será um problema no meu caso em específico.

Comment: Tente o fullcopyconvert. [fullcopyconvert.com.br](http://www.fullcopyconvert.com.br)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente o script **mysql2sqlite.sh**: https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776#file-mysql2sqlite-sh

Como descrito no header, a forma de usar:

`./mysql2sqlite.sh myDbase | sqlite3 database.sqlite`

Se tiver **Ruby** instalado você pode fazer o seguinte, utilizar o pacote **Sequel** através desse comando e depois executa-lo:

```
  $ gem install sequel
  $ sequel mysql://user:password@host/database -C sqlite://db.sqlite
```

Comment: Funcionou, ele gerou um erro com apenas um das tabelas "no such table: <tabela>" que resolvi manualmente.